# How to update TestCase staus (pass/fail) in TFS using TFS Java SDK?

Tags: tfs

I have made the connection with Tfs and able to identify my project but after that i am stuck.
Is it even possible or not ?

Please help,
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you mean you want to update the results (Pass/Fail) for **a particular test case in MTM**  or the "test" page in web portal using Java SDK ?

Answer (score 0):

For now, there's no related Java SDK in TFS to modify tests and update the test results.

However, you could try to use  **Rest Api** for updating Test Case results.

*Get a test case*

```
GET https://{instance}/DefaultCollection/{project}/_apis/test/plans/{plan}/suites/{suite}/testcases/{case}?api-version={version}
```

More detail info please refer this tutorial: [Update test results for a test run](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/test/results)